# Why does PowerShell Pipeline.Output.ReadToEnd return an empty collection?

Tags: c#, powershell

Using C# with System.Management.Automation to run a PowerShell command - I'm trying to understand the purpose/intention of the Pipeline.Output property.  This code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var results = new List<PSObject>();
        var stdout = new List<PSObject>();

        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-ChildItem"));

                results.AddRange(pipeline.Invoke());
                stdout.AddRange(pipeline.Output.ReadToEnd());
            }
            runspace.Close();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("results.Count: {0}", results.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("stdout.Count: {0}", stdout.Count);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
results.Count: 7
stdout.Count: 0
```

I would expect both counts to be 7.  The documentation is sparse on [Pipeline.Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.output(v=vs.85).aspx).  Can anyone shed some light on what Pipeline.Output is supposed to be used for?  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Invoke()` it returns the output immediately - `Output` only gets populated when you invoke the pipeline asynchronously.

Example, invoking and waiting for maximum a second:

```
pipeline.InvokeAsync();
pipeline.Output.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
if(pipeline.PipelineStateInfo.State == PipelineState.Completed) {
    stdout.AddRange(pipeline.Output.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Or better yet, set up an event handler for the [StateChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.statechanged(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! So if you are running synchronously, it is useless.

Comment: @Skrymsli yes, because it get's read and returned immediately - insert a break and you'll see that `pipeline.Output.EndOfPipeline == true` as soon as `Invoke()` returns